# Where are Lightning Components event properties documented?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to see what the lightning-input element's value in the onchange event (its a toggle element0).

I can't seem to find the documentation for the Lightning Components event properties. Specifically, the lightning-input onchange event.

We are not even told what property the change value is stored in. The event also uses a Proxy, which to my knowledge doesn't contain the properties at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most events are "native" events, or at least a facsimile thereof, meaning you can simply check the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network). For example, to see if a toggle is checked:

```
 onChangeHandler(event) {
     console.log(event.target.checked);
 }
```

In general, there is no documentation for most events, because they (should be) easy to deduce if you know how events work in JavaScript. There's very few surprises in the API, and this is intentional by design.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!